# Android Studio Bumblebee AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, mobile-development

I have installed the last version of android studio but i have this error when i start execute my project, the emulator don't working.
I have trying a lot of solution but none of them work with me.
please HELP !!!

[AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMA2O.jpg)

Comment: Did you tried standard acations like: Studio restart, check free space on your disk, project clean up and rebuild?

Comment: @AnatoliiShuba  I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to your Gradle being not updated. Try doing this -

1.Go to File

2.Project Structure

3.Project

4.Change "Android Gradle Plugin Version" - 7.0.1

5.Change "Gradle Version" - 7.0.2

6.Apply and OK

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work

Comment: can you try making a new project with just empty activity and run it.